# Away3d SWC: some classes are missingg

Tags: actionscript-3, swc, away3d

I downloaded the built version of Away3D 4.1.6 and imported to my Flash Pro CS6. But there some classes are missing:

```
away3d.entities.Mesh
away3d.entities.Camera
away3d.entities.Sprite3D
```

maybe other classes, too. (I've not compared).
There are no errors when compiling this code:

```
var mesh:Mesh = new Mesh(new CubeGeometry());
```

but, I cannot view the available properties and functions, when I put a dot after the variable `mesh`.
After this I downloaded source files of away3d, but compiling takes about a minute. So, it gets boring to work. What should I do?

Comment: I use the SWC in my projects and it works as it should but I'm using FlashDevelop... not Flash. Make sure you have added the swc to your built path in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug too. I solved this problem by generating SWC of their own. Just download source files and create a lib project (FB).

PS. my SWC file is 20% less than default. I don't now why.